# sending mail in php if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

Tags: php, pdo

I have a php mailing script, `sendmail.php` that works when I run it with a simple html script and `if(isset($_POST['btn_send']))` command.

But I want to integrate this script in a php form script, `solliciteerform.php` that I have.
The form first validates the user input and when there're no errors sends the user input to my mysql db via a prepared statement PDO.

for that I'm using

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && $geslachtErr== "" && $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== "" && $emailErr== "" && $telErr== "" && $afileErr== "") { 

          $servername = "xxxxx.eu.mysql";
          $username = "xxxxxx";
          $password = "xxxxx";

          try {
              $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=xxxxxx", $username, $password);
              // set the PDO error mode to exception
              $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

              /***
               irrelevant code 
               ***/

              if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) 
              {

              // prepare sql and bind parameters
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sollicitatie_form (geslacht, voornaam, familienaam, email, tel, afile, type) 
                VALUES (:geslacht, :voornaam, :familienaam, :email, :tel, :final_file, :file_type)");

                $stmt->bindParam(':geslacht', $geslacht);
                $stmt->bindParam(':voornaam', $voornaam);
                $stmt->bindParam(':familienaam', $familienaam);
                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
                $stmt->bindParam(':tel',$tel);
                $stmt->bindParam(':final_file', $final_file);
                $stmt->bindParam(':file_type', $file_type);


                $stmt->execute();

                ?>
                <script>
                alert('successfully uploaded');
                  window.location.href='thank.php';
                </script>
                <?php

                exit();
              }
            }
          catch(PDOException $e)
              {
              echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
              }

          $conn->null;
        }
```

This scripts works when tested without the `sendmail.php`.

So the problem is not with the `sendmail.php` or with my `solliciteerform.php` as they both work separately.

The issue that I'm having is that I want to sent the user a mail after

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && $geslachtErr== "" && $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== "" && $emailErr== "" && $telErr== "" && $afileErr== "")
```

But before the data is sent to my database....

I've tried two solutions but neither have worked....:

---

> Solution 1:

In the top of my `solliciteerform.php` adding `include ('Send-HTML-mail-in-PHP/mailer/sendmail.php');`

Than in my `sendmail.php` I replace `if(isset($_POST['btn_send']))`

with:

```
if(($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && $geslachtErr== "" && $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== "" && $emailErr== "" && $telErr== "" && $afileErr== ""){
```

The result is that `solliciteerform.php` runs as it's supposed to do but I don't get an email.

---

> Solution 2:

On the top of my `solliciteerform.php` I've added:

```
 include ('Send-HTML-mail-in-PHP/mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
```

Then before:

```
 if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && $geslachtErr== "" && $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== "" && $emailErr== "" && $telErr== "" && $afileErr== ""){
```

I've added:

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

and after the

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && $geslachtErr== "" && $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== "" && $emailErr== "" && $telErr== "" && $afileErr== ""){
```

I've paste all the code that's in `sendmail.php`.

---

When I do this than my `solliciteerform.php` doesn't even run. Get an error page.

Whats the best solution for what I want to achieve?

Comment: which errors are you getting?

Comment: @B.Desai, Page could not be loaded

Comment: Turn on php error reporting. add `error_reporting(-1);` to the start of your script.

Also you should put the mailing part in a function, then you can include the file containing the function at the start of your page. And call it whenever you need it with the variables you want.

Comment: No, what **PHP** errors are you getting?

Comment: maybe you need to increase the error logging level, but there should be some sort of error message (maybe in the logs)

Answer (score 0):

WouterS,

In your IF condition, try removing one condition at a time... and see if that fixes it. i.e.

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && $geslachtErr== "" && $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== "" && $emailErr== "" && $telErr== ""){
```

Then

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && $geslachtErr== "" && $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== "" && $emailErr== ""){
```

Then

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && $geslachtErr== "" && $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== ""){
```

etc.

Lastly, if you have already created an instance of PHPMailer in sendmail.php, then you wouldn't need to re-create it... as you are already including sendmail.php file in your solliciteerform.php

So I would remove the following:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

Hope this helps!

-Rush