# Sending html mail with function

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I've been working on this for ages and just can't find the issue. Hope somebody is so kind enough to help me out.

I've made a function for my mailing script. The function is inside  `useful_functions.inc.php`

```
<?php
include ('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');

function sendmail($mail)
{
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);  

  if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && $geslachtErr== "" && $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== "" && $emailErr== "" && $telErr== "" && $afileErr== "")
  {
    $full_name  = "Sofie Doe";
    $email      = "sofie@gmail.com";
    $subject    = "HTML test mail.";
    $text_message    = "Hello ".$full_name.",<br /><br /> This is a test email in html.";         

    $message  = "<html><body>";

    $message .= "<table width='100%' bgcolor='#e0e0e0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";

    $message .= "<tr><td>";

    $message .= "<table align='center' width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='max-width:650px; background-color:#fff; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'>";

    $message .= "<thead>
          <tr height='80'>
            <th colspan='4' style='background-color:#f5f5f5; border-bottom:solid 1px #bdbdbd; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#333; font-size:34px;' >TEST</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>";


    $message .= "</table>";

    $message .= "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</table>";

    $message .= "</body></html>";

    try
    {
      $mail->IsSMTP(); 
      $mail->isHTML(true);
      $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
      $mail->SMTPSecure = "STARTTLS";                 
      $mail->Host       = "mailout.one.com";      
      $mail->Port       = 587;             
      $mail->AddAddress($email);
      $mail->Username   ="joe@gmail.com";  
      $mail->Password   ="Password";            
      $mail->SetFrom("joe@gmail.com");
      $mail->AddReplyTo("joe@gmail.com");
      $mail->Subject    = $subject;
      $mail->Body     = $message;
      $mail->AltBody    = $message;
    }
  }
}

?>
```

I have a form, `test.php`. I start them test.php with

```
<?php
include ('useful_functions.inc.php')
sendmail($mail);
?>
```

When I run `test.php` I keep getting HTTP ERROR 500

I've tested the exact mailer with a simple html form and calling it the same way and it works.
My `test.php` works when I remove `sendmail($mail)` and remove the function in my `useful_function.inc.php`

Why is this not working?

Comment: a 500 is a server error; check your logs and/or enable error reporting

Comment: Your `try` statement is missing a `catch()` block. That's a syntax error. A good IDE would have warned you  about this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Enabling error reporting rarely helps with 500 errors. If there's a syntax error, the `error_reporting()` call will not be executed.

Comment: @Barmar well; 50% of my comment applies ;-)

Comment: @Barmar where is the missing `catch()` as I don't see it.

Comment: @Barmar that's a repost to which they placed an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44589556/1415724 but it's not a "solution"; does this constitute as a repost? I placed a comment under that "answer".

Comment: @WouterS You have `try { ... }` it needs to have at least one `catch` block after it. The whole point of `try` is so you can write code that runs if an error happens during it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm sorry about this, should I close the other topic as there was no solution to my question and the question was also different. Here it goes about working with a function. Not in the other topic.

Comment: @WouterS great but you need to delete your other question, otherwise it will get closed as an exact duplicate. You  posted an answer in the other one https://stackoverflow.com/q/44588828/1415724 that I placed a comment under.

Comment: @WouterS if it were another topic, then why did you post an answer with the same code in the question here? Edit: to which you only deleted the answer, I am getting a bit confused.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, I've messed up. Tried to delete the other topic but without succes.

Comment: @WouterS There are no upvoted answers so I can't see why you can't delete the other question. If it still doesn't let you, you can flag your (other) question to a moderator to delete it for you, that's if you want it deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you have the email "send itself" by modifying `try{}` to include `$mail->Send();`?

Your "try" will become:

```
try
{
  $mail->IsSMTP(); 
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "STARTTLS";                 
  $mail->Host       = "mailout.one.com";      
  $mail->Port       = 587;             
  $mail->AddAddress($email);
  $mail->Username   ="joe@gmail.com";  
  $mail->Password   ="Password";            
  $mail->SetFrom("joe@gmail.com");
  $mail->AddReplyTo("joe@gmail.com");
  $mail->Subject    = $subject;
  $mail->Body     = $message;
  $mail->AltBody    = $message;
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK\n";
  } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
  }
```